# Weird C++ Allocation Magic

Tags: c++

I was working on a project and wanted to make a Regional Allocator (Sometimes known as a Bump up Allocator) thats standard C++ complient. I had written an allocator like this before in C, So I ended up with something like this (For anyone wondering why I am using intptr_t* instead of void*, its because of alignment issues I had experienced running in C with x86):

```cpp
template <class T>
class RegionAllocator {

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    RegionAllocator() : size(0), capacity(STANDARD_ALLOCATOR_SIZE) {
        data = (intptr_t*)std::malloc(sizeof(intptr_t)*STANDARD_ALLOCATOR_SIZE);
        if (!data) throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    template <class U>
    RegionAllocator(const RegionAllocator<U>& other) {
        data = (intptr_t*)std::malloc(sizeof(intptr_t)*other.get_capacity());
        if (!data) throw std::bad_alloc();
        memcpy(data, other.get_data(), other.get_size() * sizeof(intptr_t));
        size = other.get_size();
        capacity = other.get_capacity();
    }
    ~RegionAllocator() {
        std::free(data);
    }
    inline size_type to_allocator_space(const size_type n) {
        return ((n * sizeof(T)) + (sizeof(intptr_t) - 1)) / sizeof(intptr_t);
    }
    pointer allocate(size_type n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
            return nullptr;
        }
        size_type nn = to_allocator_space(n);
        if (size + nn > capacity) {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
            return nullptr;
        }
        pointer value = (pointer)(data + size);
        size += nn;
        return value;
    }
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) noexcept {
        if ((size_type)p < (size_type)data) return;
        size_type nn = to_allocator_space(n);
        size_type pn = to_allocator_space((size_type)p);
        if (to_allocator_space((char*)p - (char*)data) + nn == size) {
            size -= nn;
        }
    }
    inline size_type max_size() const noexcept {
        return static_cast<size_type>(capacity*sizeof(intptr_t)) / sizeof(T);
    }
    template<class U> bool operator==(const RegionAllocator<U>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return other.data == this->data && other.size == this->size && other.capacity == this->capacity;
    }
    template<class U> bool operator!=(const RegionAllocator<U>& other) const noexcept
    {
        return other.data != this->data || other.size != this->size || other.capacity != this->capacity;
    }
    inline const intptr_t* get_data() const {
        return data;
    }
    inline size_type get_size() const {
        return size;
    }
    inline size_type get_capacity() const {
        return capacity;
    }
private:
    intptr_t* data;
    size_type size;
    size_type capacity;
};
```

And a test case of this:

```cpp
std::vector<int, RegionAllocator<int>> vector;
vector.push_back(1);
vector.push_back(2);
vector.push_back(3);
for (size_t i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i) {
    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
}
return 0;
```

For a little bit of context, I am using a project with a 3 step build modes:

- Debug - debug symbols on, optimizations off
- Release - debug symbols on, optimizations on
- Dist - debug symbols off, optimizations on

I was banging my head against the wall for the longest time - I couldn't figure out why the compiler decided to double delete my "data", until I changed the mode from "Debug" to "Release", not expecting anything to happen, but to my surprise the code worked. Dist also worked.

I'm sure there is some "deep" check the compiler does, when you tell it to optimize the code, that makes it realise some sort of property of the allocator but I'm not quite sure.

[NOTE] I figured out that C++ was calling to the same std::free(data) twice by basically letting the memory leak in the destructor which temporarily fixed the problem.

[NOTE] This was tested with MSVC on Windows

[NOTE] Changing the C++ standard did not fix the problem for Debug.

Comment: What happens if you mark `RegionAllocator::operator=` as deleted?  Currently `RegionAllocator` is  breaking the rule of 3.

Comment: @RichardCritten the issue still persists

Comment: No idea if this is the sorce of the issue, but your allocator doesn't meet [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) requirements - particularly, copy constructor should create object for which `operator==` returns `true`.

Comment: You don't seem to use `pn` in `RegionAllocator::deallocate` - is that intentional? Are you compiling this with warnings enabled?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thank you for pointing that out. Yes I forgot to remove it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No, but thank you for the resource none the less!

Comment: You can't allocate in the constructor and free in the destructor of an allocator. You also can't delete the copy operations, because allocators must be copyable. If you have a memory resource that the allocator needs to operate on, then it must be managed outside the allocator in the way that [pmr::polymorphic_allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator) does it. The interface for _Allocator_ does not permit storing the memory resource in the allocator itself.

Comment: Thank you @user17732522 , could you elaborate a little bit further on what you said about using polymorphic_allocators and build it up to a full answer so I can confirm and maybe even select it as "correct answer". Thank you

Comment: A standard C++ allocator object does **not** manage its own piece of memory. Your class is anything but an allocator.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks for the responce. An allocator is a really loose term and in my  view I see it as "something that is able to allocate and deallocate memory respectively". Given that my "RegionalAllocator" allocates and deallocates memory, it's safe for me to assume it is an allocator. A formal answer that could display how something like this could be achieved with your definition on allocator would be definitely helpful. Thanks

Comment: @DimiturKarabuyukov One of the [Allocator requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) is that if you copy-construct a new one, then it should be `==` the old one, i.e. a copy of the allocator must be able to deallocate memory allocated by the original instance. Therefore the allocator can only hold a reference to the actual memory pool from which it allocates. It can't own the memory resource. So your allocator should only hold the `data` pointer, but should never allocatote/deallocate it.

Comment: Instead the allocator's user should provide the pointer to the allocator via its constructor. The `pmr` features are a generalization of this approach that is additionally runtime-polymorphic.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you for the insightful information. I'm sure its very simple for you to do, but could you please form it into an answer (for stack overflow), since all of your intel on the question has been very helpful.

Comment: There are many meanings to the word allocator. One meaning specific to C++ is "something that satisfies the requirements set forth in [\[allocator.requirements\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements) and that can be used as an argument type for the standard library containers". Since you are trying to use your class as an argument of a standard library container, you better make sure it is an allocator in that specific sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) interface is specified, you can't have the allocator itself (uniquely) own the memory pool from which it allocates.

Copying an allocator must result in an instance that compares equal to the original and that is therefore able to deallocate an allocation made by the original instance.

To achieve this both original and copy must reference the same memory resource.

So, the standard approach for this followed in the standard library e.g. with `pmr::allocator` is to separate the memory resource and the allocator into two classes. The user then manages the memory resource themselves and only provides a reference to it to the allocator via constructor argument. The allocator itself is essentially stateless except for holding a reference to the memory resource.

In your case, that would mean that you get rid of the destructor, let the templated "copy" constructor naively copy all members, and change the default constructor to

```
RegionAllocator(intptr_t* data) : data(data), //...
```

(Of course you might want to abstract the `intptr_t*` into something analogues to `pmr::memory_resource`.)

Also, the `size` member must be reworked so that its value is shared among all copies of the allocator so that they agree on what has or hasn't been allocated (e.g. by using a `shared_ptr` or integrating it into the memory resource abstraction). The copies must compare equal, so `operator==`/`operator!=` should only compare the `data` member.

For e.g. a stack-based allocator this is the only workable approach, but in your case, since you only need the memory region to be heap-allocated, I guess you could alternatively store a `std::shared_ptr` to it and thereby have shared ownership among equal allocators instead of having the user manage the memory resource.

In that case you can keep the default constructor, but you need to replace `data` with a `std::shared_ptr<void>` which is then copied in the templated "copy" constructor, which effectively means a reference to the same memory resource is stored in the copy and a reference count will assure deallocation of the memory resource only when no allocator instance referencing it will remain.

---

In either case, you must of course also assure that all allocator instances agree on the what has already been allocated, i.e. they also need to refer to a shared `size`. How you implement this is up to you. It can again be a shared pointer or integrated into the memory resource abstraction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight. Truly a good answer to my question. One thing to note tho, for anyone else checking this out is shard_ptr has overhead and just specifying the data doesn't have it. Its a small thing, but small changes go a long way. 

Thank you once again

Comment: @DimiturKarabuyukov Also see my edit regarding `size`.